# Inconsistent behaviour between lein run and REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm new to clojure and try to learn it by solving questions from https://www.4clojure.com.
The task is to implement the flatten function.
This is my implementation:

```
(ns clojure-noob.core                                                           
  (:gen-class))                                                                 

(defn -main                                                                     
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."                                             
  []                                                                            
  (= ((fn [coll]                                                                
        (let [flat (fn [coll]                                                   
                     (when-let [s (seq coll)]                                   
                       (if (sequential? (first s))                              
                         (concat (flat (first s)) (flat (rest s)))              
                         (cons (first s) (flat (rest s))))))]                   
          (flat coll)))                                                         
      '((1 2) 3 [4 [5 6]]))                                                     
     '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
```

When I run it in REPL like *(-main)* I get true.

When I run it as *lein run* I get this exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: flat in this context, compiling:(clojure_noob/core.clj:11:42)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6688)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3766)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6870)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3834)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6870)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$IfExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:2797)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6001)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6319)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6001)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$IfExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:2797)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6001)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6319)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6001)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5380)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3972)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6866)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$300(Compiler.java:38)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6269)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6001)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5380)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3972)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6866)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3766)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6870)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:1009)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6863)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6001)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5380)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3972)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6866)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6856)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$300(Compiler.java:38)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:589)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6931)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
        at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at user$eval1036$fn__1038.invoke(form-init8418556840412273777.clj:1)
        at user$eval1036.invokeStatic(form-init8418556840412273777.clj:1)
        at user$eval1036.invoke(form-init8418556840412273777.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: flat in this context
        at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:221)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:7164)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:7108)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:7069)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6648)
        ... 128 more

I suspect it has something to do with namespaces, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the let binding for `flat`, you refer to `flat`, which is not visible yet. There is an optional name argument to `fn` which you can use to resolve this issue.

```
(defn -main                                                                     
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."                                             
  []                                                                            
  (= ((fn [coll]                                                                
        (let [flat (fn flat [coll]                                              
                     (when-let [s (seq coll)]                                   
                       (if (sequential? (first s))                              
                         (concat (flat (first s)) (flat (rest s)))              
                         (cons (first s) (flat (rest s))))))]                   
          (flat coll)))                                                         
      '((1 2) 3 [4 [5 6]]))                                                     
     '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
```

Also, the code can be simplified significantly without changing the meaning:

```
(defn -main                                                                     
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."                                             
  []                                                                            
  (let [flat (fn flat [[el & els :as coll]]                                     
               (when coll                                                       
                 (if (sequential? el)                                           
                   (concat (flat el) (flat els))                                
                   (cons el (flat els)))))]                                     
    (= (flat [[1 2] 3 [4 [5 6]]])                                               
       [1 2 3 4 5 6])))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Your simplification does not work for the input `()`.